# How read pixel of an image without canvas

Tags: javascript, image

How to get all pixel info (RGB) of an image using JavaScript. I can't use CANVAS.

Just reading an image from local disk and parse the pixels. I don't want to render img on the page.

Comment: How come you can't use <canvas>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. Javascript cannot read plain binary data from files on local disk (for obvious security reasons).